# Using ng-annotate with angular cli

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-cli, ng-upgrade

I have an existing angular.js application, which I am in the process of upgrading to angular with NgUpgrade. I am also trying to move to using angular cli as the build system. `ng serve` and `ng build` works perfectly, but I am having trouble with `ng build -prod`.

For the orginal application, I used gulp for building, and as a intermediate step i transformed the input files with ng-annotate. I am having a hard time getting this to work with angular cli.

Is there any way to integrate ng-annotate with `ng build -prod`? Or any other way to process the angular.js files before minification?

Comment: hello, have you been able to resolve your problem ? I would be interested. thx

Comment: @Cyril Sorry, I never found a way to solve this.

Comment: I finally solved this by using Webpack directly with the 'ng-annotate-webpack-plugin' !

Comment: @Cyril can you please show us your webpack config and how you run the client server?

Comment: Did you eject the Angular CLI configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I did this using [babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate), which adds the annotations to the source files, in a permanent manner (so, you only need to run it once).

I put detailed instructions in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65501689/303914).

Notice Babel should not be added to your Angular project. Instead, you create a second project, and execute Babel in there. Babel will read the files from the folder you specify, and generate the annotated files in another folder you specify.

After you run this once, you can forget about ng-annotate.